# All contract calls returning null

Tags: web3js

I'm building a browser extension that uses web3.js over websocket to Infura and for some reason all my contract calls are returning null in my production build. When testing the app as a web app in the browser all calls work just fine. But when I build and load the app as an extension, all calls just silently return null without any errors or warnings. There are no CORS warnings or errors either, so that doesn't seem to be the issue.

My question is what all could cause a contract call to return null?

It's a bit annoying that I have to ask this question because there should be an error but instead it silently just returns null